# Git verify pushed commits

Tags: git, github, gnupg

I have some unverified commits here: https://github.com/DeBos99/portable-strlen/commits/master

Is there any way to verify this commits and keep them at the end of the list of commits?

Answer (score 1):

*Verified* means the commit was signed with a GPG key known to Github. To "verify" commits you need to sign them and the only way to do that is to do interactive rebase during which sign every commit. All rebased commits will be changed so you have to force-push the branch.

Comment: I know what means 'verify', but you didn't answer my question. If I will rebase everything, so every commit will be signed, will they be 'on the same place' (same timestamp/date etc.) or these will be counted as new commits?

Comment: "All rebased commits will be changed ..."  That means they will count as new commits.

Comment: Commits in a branch are shown according to their position in the branch, i.e. according to DAG.